# Contact Form 7 - validation message disappears on mouseover

Tags: javascript, jquery, wordpress, contact-form-7

I need to stop the following:

span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip

from disappearing on the mouseover event.

I have looked at [Contact Form 7 - Customizing Validation Error Messages](https://contactform7.com/customizing-validation-error-messages/) and I have not used the code in question to load the form.

The form in question has a textarea that is required, everthing else is hidden, and no other input is required.

I have had to use CSS to locate the error message beneath the field itself.

My error message appears when I hover over it with a mouse in Firefox and Chrome. Any help would be appreciated

Comment: Can you add HTML propotype and CSS of your problem. Its difficult to envision your problem from here.

Comment: You can fix it by CSS `.wpcf7-form-control-wrap:hover .wpcf7-not-valid-tip, .wpcf7-form-control:focus + .wpcf7-not-valid-tip { display:block !important; }`

Comment: @SurudoiRyu, the problem still occurs whilst using this CSS. It will remain on screen for longer, but once the textarea looses focus, it will still disappear off the screen, acting like it set to the floating-tip style - which it is not.

Comment: @BrettCanfield are you calling the contact form by its shortcode on a page/widget ? or within the code of the template ? perhaps link where i can see/test it. I use it as shortcode on a page with the default contact form template and i do not have the same problem.

Comment: @SurudoiRyu,  I use a short code, fairly simple page to be honest, that shortcode and nothing else on it. [Contact Form Page](https://bbs4you.com/contact-us/)

Comment: @BrettCanfield have you tried my solution already ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your Custom CSS add the following:

```
span.wpcf7-not-valid-tip {
   display: block !important;
   opacity: 1 !important;
}
```

This will stop hiding and fading the messages.